# Why ASIO sync write to newtork fails to send data second time?

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

Trying to send multiple requests via one connection:

```
int count = boost::asio::write(socket, request); // this will result in normal count2

int count2 =    boost::asio::write(socket, request);  // this one gives zero
```

However cont2 is equal to zero meaning that id does not send data.. Ho to fix it

Adding more code for getting better view:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

boost::asio::streambuf lastResponse;

// Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
char *host = "somewebsie.coom";
char *requestPath = "/somequery";
tcp::resolver::query query(host, "http");
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

// Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io option2(true);
boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io command(true);


double startTime,endTime;
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);  
request_stream << "GET "<< requestPath <<" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "<<host <<":80\r\n\r\n";

boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
socket.set_option(option);
socket.io_control(command);

startTime = getRealTime( );

// Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
// server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
// allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.


int count2 =    boost::asio::write(socket, request);
 count2 =   boost::asio::write(socket, request);
 bool isopen = socket.is_open(); // return true...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `write` with a stream you just emptied?! Trying to write zero bytes is not a good idea.

You're not trying to send multiple requests. There is only one request in your code, and you've already sent it.

Comment: True! After four years of c# is hard to get back to c++ :)